# org-clock-display not working for part of the outline items

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I have tried to use org-clock-display (`C-c C-x C-d`) in order to know how much time I have spent on an activity, which is broken down further. The first three outlines won't have their time spent accounted for, as shown in the image below. From module 4 onward everything works fine.

[image: Org tree]

I do no know how to debug this, and have tried to check if the structure of the time appointments are correct, which by visual inspection they seem to be. Is there something I am missing or that could help me to debug this issue?

Comment: There is not enough information here. You'll need to tell us not only the *output*, but even more importantly, the *input*. The best thing to do is to come up with a minimal example Org file that when processed, shows the problem: then people can try it out. As it stands, your question is not detailed enough to allow anybody to answer it.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for letting me know it is still not detailed enough. Kinda hard to ask when you don't know very well the subject.

Comment: You could just do as I asked: post the Org file that generated the output above.

Comment: You are right, I could have, but I just gave up after this slightly unpleasant experience, but no worries, I understand what you mean. Thanks anyways. For now, I have gathered the hours from those activities manually. Will post an answer myself if I figure out so others might benefit from it.

Comment: Could it be that those dates fall out of the current `org-clock-display-default-range`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749731/orgmode-logbook-drawer-total-time-not-calculated-as-expected Try `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-d` and select interactive to customize the date range.